# Issue when running in a android google API (2.2 platform)

Tags: android, api, spinner

New to android development, be gentle haha. I am wanting to populate a spinner with data from my SQLite database. I have a table that is pre-populated and am able to query it successfully. Problem is that I am able to populate the spinner when running it in my emulater (android 2.2) but not able to run it on my portable devices (tablet and phone) (running android 2.2). I get a generic error message saying that: "applilcation...(app name)...has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." However, I did notice that in my emulator it works beautifully with the build path being set to "Android 2.2" and yet when I change it to the Google API (2.2 platform), I then encounter it. Am I missing somthing? here is the code being used to populate the spinner control:

```
 final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 
    db.open(); 
    Cursor c = db.getAllStates();

    startManagingCursor(c);             
    String[] columns = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_STATE_NAME};
    int[] to = new int []{android.R.id.text1};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, columns, to);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //get reference to the spinner...
    Spinner s =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_state);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);


    db.close();
```

Here is my code to get the data:

```
        public Cursor getAllStates() 
    {    
        Cursor c = null;
                    c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_STATE, new String[] { KEY_STATE_ID, KEY_STATE_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);


        //c = db.rawQuery("select * from tblStates", null);

        return c;   
    }
```

LocCat:

```
: INFO/Database(305): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: tblStates
: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(305): Shutting down VM
: WARN/dalvikvm(305): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{king.chad.SDE/king.chad.SDE.BuildingAddressActivity}
: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblStates: , while compiling: SELECT _id, stateName FROM tblStates
: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with the stackstrace (which can be found in the Logcat (in the DDMS))

Comment: Added locat error message, but it doesn't make sense that when running the same code with build path set to Android 2.2 it works and when changing it to Google API's (2.2 Platform) it doesn't...

Comment: ok, the database that it was referencing was and older version that was missing tables. I deleted it and added it back with the most recent one and it works, for the emulator. But still doesn't work with my device.

Comment: Is it possible that I may not be including something? Maybe like a library reference? or something that my app would need? If I comment out the code above the app works on my device, but uncomment it and it doesn't. At the same time commented or uncommented it works with the emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...after much searching and hair pulling I inserted break points all throughout my code and debugged the hell out of it only to find that the directory (when running on the device vs the emulator) could not be found. Therefore it couldn't read from the database that I pre-populated which explains why the data wasn't getting binded to the spinner control. So at the beginning of my activity I checked for the directory and if it didn't exist I created it. Problem resolved. If anyone else is having same issue as I did feel free to post and I'll be glad to shed what light I can, thanks to all for your suggestions!