# code works on emulator but not on Phone

Tags: android, database, android-emulator

have a look at the code below...

this works fine and deletes a message when the menu item is pressed on the emulator but it does not do anything when the same application with the same database and the same code is installed on the Phone(Samsung Galaxy S)

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    String s = (String) ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position))
                .getString(2);

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.delete:

        Log.v("", "You Clicked "+ s);
        dba = new DBAdapter(this);
        dba.open();
        dba.deleteMessage(s);       
        dba.close();

        //  return true;

    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Although the Log.v also displays the number that is being clicked but why isnt this function doing anything on the phone while it works and deletes records wwhen on the emulator

Comment: Have you connected your phone to your computer to see if the `Log`-statement is shown?

Comment: May be the messages are stored on SD Card?

Comment: yes i am using USB debugging and there aint anylog cat displayed except the one i displayed like Log.v()

Comment: there aint any SDCard present in the phone

Comment: Whats the log you get on it? Is it an exception (Usually comes up red) .

Comment: Does the application show? Or does just nothing happen?

Comment: yes the application runs normally only the method above does not deletes my messages while on the phone..if the same code is on the emulator it works fine and deletes the messages... and there isnt any exception thrown

Comment: it should be related to the paths as 'nithinreddy' says.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546149/issue-when-running-in-a-android-google-api-2-2-platform

Comment: the related question posts an error also but i simply dont get an error at all....just the Log.v() is printed that i am using in this method..

Comment: Just wondering - have you looked at the database file's permissions?

Comment: @Julian Higginson No i dont know about that...what are those please tell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code solved my problem....it works both on phone and the emulator

```
DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        dbh.getWritableDatabase().delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
```